# "background-positon:center" does not work with "background-attachement:scroll"

Tags: css, background-image

I am making a layout with an background in body. I need to center it both horizontally and vertically. For that purpose I use background-position:center.

```
 background-image:url('address');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;  
  background-position:50% 50%;
```

However, the background not positoned correctly vertically: you can see only half of the image in the top of the screen. Check it here [link to codepen](http://codepen.io/lessismore/pen/QKpAkr).

As a solution I tried to use images with different sizes and background-position:50% 50%. Then I double-checked other background-relative selectors and found that if I add background-attachement and change it from its default value which is scroll to fixed, than the image is centered correctly.

Can anybody explain please why this happens?

Comment: Your codepen link doesn't work, which is one of the biggest reason to put the code snippet inline, using Stack snippet, so please update so future users can see the whole issue.

Comment: If any of the posted answers solved your question, please accept it by clicking the gray check mark next to the answer of your choice, if not, let us know that we can do to make one that does

Answer (score 1):

It happens if you didn't gave the `body` a height, as its default is 0.

The `body`'s height is based on its content, and a background image doesn't set it.

Here is a sample showing how you need to do

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Sometimes it can create other issues when one need to give the `body` a height, and when, a positioned `div` is one option

```css
#bkgdiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div id="bkgdiv"></div>
```

So, based on how/if you need to use `background-attachment: scroll` and/or positioned `div`'s, here is a sample showing their behavior when one scroll (and a [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tot6srL6/1/) to play with)

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: scroll;
}
#bkgdiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/180/0f0);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
#bkgdivfixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/160/ff0);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div id="bkgdiv"></div>
<div id="bkgdivfixed"></div>
<div style="width: 5px; height: 150vh; background: red; margin: 5px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to gave background to body, its really simple task.

initially you need to write css for body and html

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The next ting is you need to gave background css to the body

```
body {
  background-image: url(https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OixOH_h84Po/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Okey now the image seems to be the center of the body(screen),
Now you can adjust the size using  background-size property.

```
background-size: cover;
```

The images enlarged enough to cover the entire screen.

```
background-size: contain;
```

The images enlarged up to the height or width(which is smaller) of the screen.

you can give fixed size my giving size to it

```
background-size: Xpx Ypx;
```